# Чего бы кто не/ни говорил

Tags: не-или-ни

*«Знаю, что командующий Росгвардией не сдрейфит, чего бы кто **не** говорил, он настоящий мужик, подошёл, вытащил [газовый] баллон, сел в машину, мы с ним поговорили», - приводит ТАСС слова предпринимателя Дмитрия Шалая.*

Самого тассововского материала я в сети не нашел, но цитируют все дружно с НЕ.
Неужели ИАР "ТАСС" настолько просел в профессионализме?
Или тут "НЕ" законно?!

Answer (score 1):

> Так и сказал: "Знаю, что командующий Росгвардией не сдрейфит, чего бы кто **не** говорил, он настоящий мужик, подошел, вытащил [газовый] баллон, сел в машину, мы с ним поговорили", - проинформировал Мельников. ([tass.ru](https://tass.ru/proisshestviya/5655792))

При всем уважении к ТАСС, не могу согласиться с этим *не*.